# Highlight helper wipes HTML attributes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

From the Rails console:

```
> content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class='class'>amet</span>."
> helper.highlight(content, "dolor")

=> "Lorem ipsum <strong class=\"highlight\">dolor</strong> sit <span class=\"class\">amet</span>."
```

However:

```
> content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span id='id'>amet</span>."
> helper.highlight(content, "dolor")

=> "Lorem ipsum <strong class=\"highlight\">dolor</strong> sit <span>amet</span>."
```

As a matter of fact:

```
> content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href='http://127.0.0.1' class='class' id='id' style='color: #ffffff;' target='_blank' name='name' title='title'>amet</a>."
> helper.highlight(content, "dolor")

=> "Lorem ipsum <strong class=\"highlight\">dolor</strong> sit <a href=\"http://127.0.0.1\" class=\"class\" name=\"name\" title=\"title\">amet</a>."
```

So the highlight helper seems to selectively wipe some HTML-attributes in its process, but not all. Not that I care so much for `target` or `style`, but losing `id`s is rather unfortunate.

Are there options I can pass into `highlight` to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `sanitize: false` as an option:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span id='id'>amet</span>."
 => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span id='id'>amet</span>."
2.0.0-p247 :002 > helper.highlight(content, 'dolor', sanitize: false)
 => "Lorem ipsum <mark>dolor</mark> sit <span id='id'>amet</span>."
```

The sanitize helper is documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) and most of the text helpers will sanitize the content by default.